# Lambda to load file from S3 to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and facing problem connecting lambda to SQL server deployed on EC2. Below are the steps I have already taken.

1. SQL server is currently deployed on EC2 instance,
2. Lambda function is configured in same VPC(virtual private server) as of EC2 instance,
3. I am using SQL Alchemy to read data from SQL server but not able to connect successfully.

```py
    import json
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    import boto3
    import pandas as pd
    import pyodbc

    server = 'SERVERIP'
    database = 'DBName'
    user = 'USER'
    password = 'PWD'
    driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
    
    connection_string = f"mssql+pyodbc://{server}/{database}?driver={driver}?trusted_connection=yes? UID={user}?PWD={password}"

    engine = create_engine(connection_string)
    connection = engine.connect()
    df = pd.read_sql_query("Select * from dbo.SampleTable",connection)
    print(df)
    engine.close()
```

Right now I am getting below error:

```
"errorMessage": "(pyodbc.Error) ('01000', \"[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 
'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server?trusted_connection=yes?UID=xxxxxx?PWD=xxxxxx' : file not found 
(0) (SQLDriverConnect)\")\n(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)",
"errorType": "DBAPIError",
"stackTrace": [
```

Comment: What is the security group on the Lambda & EC2 instance?

Comment: all security groups and all subnets are configured with required IAM policies attached to execution role.

Comment: Please share screenshots of your security groups, VPC configuration and database settings

Comment: Isn't it saying that SQL Alchemy can't open the ODBC driver?

Comment: Please show the security groups of the Lambda and EC2 instance. Your response that the security groups have the required IAM policies indicates you don't know what a security group is, because they are not related to IAM policies in any way.

Comment: @MarkB: Its "Required IAM policies attached  to execution role"

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary: I am really sorry. Can't share security group and VPC configuration screenshot and settings.

Comment: Without seeing the security groups nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The error trace indicates that lambda isn't able to connect to the DB inside the EC2 Instance. Might be some connectivity issue between Lambda and EC2 (Even though they are on the same VPC, Give a check on the security groups)

AWS Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html

Also Check if your lambda execution role has permissions to access EC2 to create network interfaces.

Comment: Hi Beluga,
Function is deployed in all subnets and security groups of VPC. Below policies are also added:

ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups
ec2:DescribeSubnets
ec2:DescribeVpcs, 

But it is still giving same error.

Comment: Hmm, That's strange. We are missing something